# How to filter and separate nested objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the objects that have the similar value. I am trying with this but I am not getting the objects with similar values:

```
const dataWork = [
  {
    _id:1,
    firstName:'Leo',
    lastName:'Bla',
    mail:'leo.bla@gmail.com',
    certifications:[
      {_id:1, certification:'C1 Certification'},
      {_id:2, certification:'C3 Certification'}
    ],
    education:[
      {_id:1, school:'School A'}
    ],
    work:[
      {_id:1, company:'Company A', industry:'Industry A' ...},
      {_id:2, company:'Company B', industry:'Industry B' ...},
      {_id:3, company:'Company A', industry:'Industry A' ...},
      {_id:4, company:'Company C', industry:'Industry C' ...},
      {_id:5, company:'Company C', industry:'Industry C' ...},
      {_id:6, company:'Company B', industry:'Industry A' ...},
      {_id:7, company:'Company D', industry:'Industry B' ...},
    ]
  }
];
```

I want obtain this:

```
result = [
  {
   industryA:[
      {_id:1, company:'Company A' ...},
      {_id:3, company:'Company A' ...},
      {_id:6, company:'Company A' ...}
   ], 
   industryB:[
      {_id:2, company:'Company B' ...},
      {_id:7, company:'Company B' ...}
   ],
   industryC:[
      {_id:4, company:'Company C' ...},
      {_id:5, company:'Company C' ...}
   ]
  }
]
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```js
const data = {
  work:[
    {_id:1, company:'Company A', industry:'Industry A'},
    {_id:2, company:'Company B', industry:'Industry B'},
    {_id:3, company:'Company A', industry:'Industry A'},
    {_id:4, company:'Company C', industry:'Industry C'},
    {_id:5, company:'Company C', industry:'Industry C'},
    {_id:6, company:'Company B', industry:'Industry A'},
    {_id:7, company:'Company D', industry:'Industry B'}
  ]}
  const obj = {};
  data.work.map(el => {
    obj[el.industry] = obj[el.industry] ? [...obj[el.industry], el] : [el];
  })
  console.log(obj);
```